# Projection issues with merging files.

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system

New QGIS user, 2.6 Brighton.  My project CRS is default to Nad83ft / N.Carolina (US).  I loaded various polygon and line (provided to me) that have various CRS's but they still show correctly in place over USGS / ortho-imagery.  Oddly, setting each file's CRS to NAD83ft / N. Carolina moves them out of view. Clearly I'm missing something about CRS basics.

Comment: Yes you can't simply change the CRS definition. When you set each to what it actually is, it displays correctly. You should be able to export it to a modified projection if you want everything to be in NAD83 State Plane (feet) for NC by using "Save As" as indicated in this post 
http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/95786/how-to-project-vector-data-in-qgis-2-2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Essentially what I'm saying in my comment is that you should not change the CRS for those other layers but instead load them and use Save As to change the projection.

Comment: I should clarify and say that all the files showed up nicely regardless of their CRS, overlaid w/ Usgs and aerials, but on attempting to merge two property polygon layers (both in the same CRS) in order to acquire all the attribute fields of one file for the blank second file, the new file I hoped to add the attributes to is then "bumped" several 100 miles southwest.